# Spring MVC Set ListBox Value From Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, listbox

I have a list box in a view and i would like when i press a reset button the form is submitted to the Controller and the values of the list-box are re-set to their default values in the case of the Gender list box default value is "A".

The user before submit to the controller may have selected another value e.g. "M", however when i click on the re-set button the value should be defaulted back to "A". I have tried request.setAttribute("gender.genderId", "A") and request.setAttribute("genderId", "A") and none of these worked for me. Under is my code:

**View**

```
<li>
<label>Select Gender</label>
<form:select path="genderId" id="genderId" title="Select Your Gender">
<form:options items = "${gender.genderList}" itemValue="genderId" itemLabel="genderDesc" />
</form:select>
<form:errors path="genderId" class="errors"/>
</li>
```

**Controller**

Would like to set the value of gender to "A":

```
  ......
    model.addAttribute("gender", myGender);
    request.setAttribute("gender.itemValue", "A");
    model.addAttribute("updateBtnStatus","disabled");
    return new ModelAndView("officer_registration");
}
```

**Html**

```
<li>
<label>Select Gender</label>
<select id="genderId" name="genderId" title="Select Your Gender">
<option value="A">Select Gender</option><option value="F">FEMALE</option><option value="M" selected="selected">MALE</option>
</select>
</li>
```

Comment: Your `select` control is referenced as `genderId` - so I would expect you could simply add this to your controller: `model.addAttribute("genderId", "A");` prior to rendering the form?

Comment: I did this before i return the form and it didn't work

Comment: I would then confirm the values being produced by `gender.genderList` contain a value "A" by looking at the HTML source in the browser. Look at the `value` attribute of `<option>` tags to check one of them has the value "A". You can only set the value of a `select` element if the list populating the `option`s contains that value.

Comment: i updated the question with my html and its values "A" is a valid option value

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is now... Could you please update your question with what you *expect* to see and what you are *currently* seeing in your webapp. I don't now what you meant with your comment "it didn't work".

Comment: Seems unnecessary to go via controller... just use a reset button surely? `<input type="reset" value="reset"/>`